# urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:507 in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am getting this error `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:507: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>` while deploying to Google App Engine. Yesterday It was working perfectly. Today troubling. I have tried several times. But the same project works well in localhost. I am using 2 step verified gmail account and using different app specific password each time while deploy, will this be the cause for error.

Below is my app.yaml

```
application: ishamsample
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
```

Error is

```
2013-11-15 23:11:03,595 ERROR appcfg.py:2144 An error occurred processing file '': <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:507: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 196, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 192, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4985, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4976, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2581, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4417, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3338, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml, yaml_file_basename)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3265, in UpdateVersion
    return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2114, in DoUpload
    self.resource_limits = GetResourceLimits(self.rpcserver, self.config)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 437, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(GetRemoteResourceLimits(rpcserver, config))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 408, in GetRemoteResourceLimits
    version=config.version)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 409, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 387, in do_open
    raise url_error
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:507: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
2013-11-15 23:11:03 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

Comment: might be an idea to add the deploy command (minus credentials ofc).

Comment: Now I have tried and its working. I have no idea why it did not work last night and still no idea how its working now..